# Pandas csv read: dtype int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, pandas, csv

when I read a file with Pandas read I got the following Error message: 
*'mixed dtype in column(0,1) ...'*

**Column 0**: user_IDs, but only integer values;

**Column1**: parameterIDs, as a mix of integer and strings, but it would be fine as strings.

So I tried

```
dtype={'user_ID': int, 'parameterID':str)
```

The next error message I got was: *'python int too large to convert to C long'*

Then I tried to change it to a **float**, but received following message:
*'cannot safely convert pased user dtype of loat64 for object dtyped data in column 0'*

I tried low_memory=False as well, but then I get different .Count() values of some columns...

How can I convert my user_ID column properly?

I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: Can you post some example if IDs that give you this problem?

Comment: what if you use also str for user_ID ? Are you sure you do not have something wrong on that column ?

Comment: @joaquin : My IDs look like 1570000789, etc.

Comment: and @GPhilo: Setting both columns as str worked! thanks!